# matrix manipulation diagonal

Tags: r, matrix

I have a 3x3 matrices

```
 M1 <- matrix(1:9, ncol = 3)

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
```

I like to create one final `NxN` matrix by stacking this little `nxn` matrices three times diagonally. All other cells are are to be filled with 0s.

```
  Expecting a final matrix like this.

 matrix(0:0, ncol = 9, nrow = 9)

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
 [1,]    1    4    7    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [2,]    2    5    8    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [3,]    3    6    9    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [4,]    0    0    0    1    4    7    0    0    0
 [5,]    0    0    0    2    5    8    0    0    0
 [6,]    0    0    0    3    6    9    0    0    0
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    4    7
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    2    5    8
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    3    6    9
```

[image]

Not sure how to inject each matrix diagonally. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.